# How can I automatically re-size an html tag so that the text fits on a single line and does not need to wrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a typical web store and each product has an  tag with the product title. Some of the product names are very long and cause the tag to word wrap up to three lines.

Is there a way, either in pure CSS or javascript or jQuery to dynamically change the font size of the tag so that it is the maximum size necessary to fill the parent div but -without- requiring a word wrap?

So far I've tried using jQuery to add a series of classes based on the number of chars in the text, but that has been far from precise. For example:

jQuery:

```
$('h1').each( function() { 
   if( $(this).html().length > 15 )
       $(this).addClass('long');
 }
 etc...
```

CSS:

```
       h1.entry-title.long 
       { font-size: 2.2em; letter-spacing: normal; }
```

Can anyone suggest a more elegant/accurate solution?

Comment: do you need to show the complete text? if not, I would use [text-overflow:ellipsis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) and add the full text as tooltip on the element

Comment: I definitely need to show the complete text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you say that some of the product names are so long that they span 3 lines it could get pretty ugly I guess, therefore I've added the option on turning on text-overflow: ellipsis and adding the text to the title (so that the full text will appear as a tooltip on mouseover) if the font-size drops below 16px.

So... basically, what happens is that the functions turn on white-space: nowrap with a scrollbar on each of the H1's and then run a loop where font-size is reduced for every iteration until the need for a scrollbar disappear or the size meets the limit. In the end, the scrollbar is hidden again.

You just need to set the lowest acceptable size (min_font_size) and possible additional filters on H1.

On the count of elegance, I guess... Well... perhaps a shrink animation could be added?

```
jQuery.fn.hasHScrollBar = function () {
   return this.get(0).scrollWidth > this.innerWidth();
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set minimum size:
    var min_font_size = 16;

    $('h1').each(function () {
        var font_size = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
        $(this).css("white-space", "nowrap");
        $(this).css("overflow", "scroll");
        while ($(this).hasHScrollBar()) {
            if (font_size < min_font_size) {
                $(this).css("text-overflow", "ellipsis");
                break;
            }
            $(this).css("font-size", font_size + "px");
            font_size--;
        }
        $(this).css("overflow", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Possible distraction:

Add opacity 0 to body or container:

```
body {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

And a restore class:

```
.fade-in {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Normalize the page on ready (before or after the font-adjustment):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('body').addClass("fade-in");
```

Comment: This actually works. The only downside is that, on all the devices I've tested so far, it creates a noticeable visual glitch--the text displays as huge for an instant and then snaps to the proper size. Is there a way to get rid of that? (ie. to have the resizing invisible?)

Comment: That's the downside of fixing displays after everything have clicked into place and found the space to cramped. I was partially joking on the subject of elegance, but I guess a distraction is needed. I haven't actually done animations on shrinking text before, so I can't say whether it might be possible to turn it into an "Oomph" effect that might actually be an attraction.

Comment: Other than setting the default size considerably smaller and closer to how the majority appears would lessen the impact.. I guess Another way might be to create classes from the rendered font-sizes, save them to a css file and add them to each h1 somehow perhaps linked with a record id...Like a dictionary of sorts. How is the data generated?

Comment: It's a typical WordPress site. LAMP

Comment: And BTW--I did get the joke. There are apparently other solutions out there, but the client isn't paying to do more research.

Comment: I see, well, erm, I guess you could always try with something like a fade-in of body or content from opacity 0 to 1 in 0.4s, which would totally hide the transitional phase unless it's running on a very slow server with a client on a very slow connection...

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps consider to use a [responsive unit](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_responsive_text) of measure for the font, to adapt it to the [container](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/), also on resize; if the container is the body, what you are looking for is [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: When I just opened this page to see the new answers I was greeted with a new StackOverflow feature: A suggested answer. And that page has some interesting options including FitText and a solution in straight CSS using SVG.

[Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)